# Javascript and HTML form - Creating two functions with one form

Tags: javascript, function

Could you help? I have a form now that takes what is in box 1, 2, and 3 and multiples them and gives the answer. I have a separate function and form that subtracts box 4-11 (as you can see from the code). What I need help with is creating a function that can take the second function and subtract it from the first.

If it helps to explain what I am doing, the first function calculates the gross revenue. The second calculated negative expenses, but now I do not know how to minus the expenses from the gross?

Basically- I have Function that Answers A (the gross). I have function that Answers B (the expenses). But how do I subtract B from A?

Any help would be great!

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function runGross(grossForm) {

var field1 = Number(grossForm.box1.value);

var field2 = Number(grossForm.box2.value);

var field3 = Number(grossForm.box3.value);

grossForm.total.value = '$' + field1*field2*field3;

}

function runTotal(totalForm) {

var field4 = Number(totalForm.box4.value);

var field5 = Number(totalForm.box5.value);

var field6 = Number(totalForm.box6.value);

var field7 = Number(totalForm.box7.value);

var field8 = Number(totalForm.box8.value);

var field9 = Number(totalForm.box9.value);

var field10 = Number(totalForm.box10.value);

var field11 = Number(totalForm.box11.value);

totalForm.total.value = field4-field5-field6-field7-field8-field9-field10-field11;

}

</script>


<h1>How Much Can You Make as Counselor in Private Practice?</h1>
<h2><span style="color: #339966;">Adding the Total Gross Revenue</span></h2>
Use an average of cash clients and various payers. Remember, that insurance pays a little more for first appointments, and couples counseling / family therapy.

<form><span style="color: #339966;"><strong>Revenue Per Session</strong></span>: <input type="text" name="box1" size="10" maxlength="20" placeholder="Avg 50-150" />
<br/><br/>
30-35 sessions a week is traditionally fulltime. Some clinicians work more, some work less.
<br/>
<span style="color: #339966;"><strong>Sessions Per Week:</strong></span><input type="text" name="box2" size="10" maxlength="20" placeholder="Avg. 30-35"/>
<br/>
<br/>
Recommended: 48 weeks per year. That allows for 4 weeks off per year.
<br/>
<span style="color: #339966;"><strong>Weeks Per Year</strong>:</span> <input type="text" name="box3" size="10" maxlength="20" placeholder="Avg. 48-50" />
<br/>
<br/>
<strong><span style="color: #339966;">Your Total Gross Revenue:</span> </strong>

<input onclick="runGross(this.form)" type="button" value="Calculate My Gross Revenue" />
<input type="text" name="total" size="10" maxlength="20" />

</form>


<h2><span style="color: #ff0000;">Subtracting the Expenses</span></h2>
Remember to include heat, electric, water, and Internet (if applicable).

<form><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Rent & Utilities (per year):</strong></span> <input type="text" name="box4" size="10" maxlength="20" />
<br/>
<br/>
Some providers in private practice spend around 7% of revenue. Others spend 0%.
<br/>
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Marketing:</strong></span><input type="text" name="box5" size="10" maxlength="20" />
<br/>
<br/>
Will you hire a billing company (calculate 5% of revenue)? Accept credit cards (calculate 2% of revenue)?
<br/>
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Medical Billing</strong>:</span> <input type="text" name="box6" size="10" maxlength="20" />
<br/>
<br/>
These can be under $300 a year if you’re frugal, or thousands if you plan to attend conferences. 
<br/>
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>CEUs and Association Fees:</strong></span> <input type="text" name="box7" size="10" maxlength="20" />
<br/>
<br/>
Professional Liability insurance is approx $150-$350 a year.
<br/>
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Insurance:</strong></span> <input type="text" name="box8" size="10" maxlength="20" />
<br/>
<br/>
For a solo-practice, can be around $2500 a year.
<br/>
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Office Expenses:</strong></span> <input type="text" name="box9" size="10" maxlength="20" />
<br/>
<br/>

Approx $500 a year for Legal Expenses.
<br/>
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Accounting and Legal:</strong></span> <input type="text" name="box10" size="10" maxlength="20" />
<br/>
<br/>
Estimate another $1500 for the unexpected!
<br/>
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Misc. Expenses:</strong></span> <input type="text" name="box11" size="11" maxlength="20" />
<br/>
<br/>

<strong><span style="color: #339966;">Your Total Pre-Tax (Pre-Tax):</span> </strong>

<strong></strong><input onclick="runTotal(this.form)" type="button" value="Calculate My Total" />
<input type="text" name="total" size="20" maxlength="20" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it will work if you have your functions return values, like this:

```
var runGross = function (grossForm)
{
    //contents here

    return grossForm.total.value;
}
```

and

```
var runTotal = function (totalForm)
{
    //contents here

    return totalForm.total.value;
}
```

then if you want another function to find the difference:

```
var findProfit = function (runGross, runTotal)
{
    return runGross - runTotal;
}
```